# Simple slopes for interaction in Negative Binomial regression

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I am looking to obtain parameter estimates for one predictor when constraining another predictors to specific values in a negative binomial glm in order to better explain an interaction effect.

My model is something like this:

```
model <- glm.nb(outcome ~ IV * moderator + covariate1 + covariate2)
```

Because the `IV:moderator` term is significant, I would like to obtain parameter estimates for `IV` at specific values of `moderator` (i.e., at +1 and -1 SD). I can obtain slope estimates for `IV` at various levels of `moderator` using the `visreg` package but I don't know how to estimate SEs and test statistics. `moderator` is a continuous variable so I can't use the `multcomp` package and other packages designed for finding simple slopes (e.g., `pequod` and `QuantPsyc`) are incompatible with negative binomial regression. Thanks!

Comment: Consider posting a small (perhaps fake) data set so that your code actually runs.  Although, I wonder whether Cross Validated might be a better forum for your question, if it is more about statistics than programming.

Comment: There _is_ a `predict.glm` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to constrain one of the values in your regression, consider taking that variable out of the model and adding it in as an offset. For example with the sample data.

```
dd<-data.frame(
   x1=runif(50),
   x2=runif(50)
)

dd<-transform(dd, 
   y=5*x1-2*x2+3+rnorm(50)
)
```

We can run a model with both `x1` and `x2` as parameters

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2,dd)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = dd)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1           x2  
#    3.438438     4.135162    -2.154770
```

Or say that we know that the coefficient of `x2` is -2. Then we can not estimate `x2` but put that term in as an offset

```
lm(y ~ x1 + offset(-2*x2), dd)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x1 + offset(-2 * x2), data = dd)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1  
#    3.347531     4.153594
```

The `offset()` option basically just create a covariate who's coefficient is always 1. Even though I've demonstrated with `lm`, this same method should work for `glm.nb` and many other regression models.